# How can I tell which repositories have imported a Python Library published with Foundry Code Repository?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

In the Foundry Artifacts app for a specific python library, we have access to stats on which repositories have consumed that library. Beyond just linking to Artifacts, I'd like to replicate these stats for display in other apps (Workshop, Slate). I see the post request in network traffic to generate the Consumers section, which we do not seem to have access to. Executing the same post request gives me a 400 error ("Only Forge is allowed to make requests to the GraphQL-Gateway. All other clients are not supported and subject to breaks on a regular basis"). I also do not see any Foundry api endpoints that look relevant. What else is available to get this information?

[image]